# Pass file uploaded via HTTP POST to another API

Tags: node.js, multer, form-data

I have a Node.js (16.13.1) REST API using Express and one of my endpoints receives one or more uploaded files. The client (web app) uses **FormData** into which the files are appended. Once they're submitted to my API, the code there uses **multer** to grab the files from the **request** object.

Now I'm having trouble trying to send those same files to another API. **multer** attaches the files to **req.files** and each file object in that array has several properties one of which is `buffer`. I tried using the `stream` package's `Duplex` object to convert this buffer to a stream so that I could append the file to another **FormData** object, but when the server the second API is running on receives the request, I get an error from the web server saying that "a potentially dangerous request.form value was detected from the client.".

Any suggestions?

Comment: There's a similar-ish [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72876918/283366). Does that help at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am working on a nest project I was also facing this issue did some research and found that we need to create a `Readable` from the `Buffer` of that file and it's working for me.

```
// Controller
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
async uploadFile(@UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File) {
   return this.apiservice.upload(file);
}

// Service
uploadFile(file: Express.Multer.File) {
    const readstream = Readable.from(file.buffer)
    console.log(readstream)
    const form = new FormData();
    form.append('file', file, { filename: extra.filename });

    const url = `api_endpoint`;

    const config: AxiosRequestConfig = {
       headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
       },
    };
   return axios.post(url, form, config);
}
```