# How to send a Png or Jpeg image as binary to node.js server from react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, file-upload, axios

I am trying to send a file from a react web app to node.js server.

I am starting off with an html input of type file, Once user uploads their file, I trigger a post request to my Node.js server.

Once in my Node.js server, I need to send a post request to a 3rd party API (Twilio)

3rd party API needs my file as binary data.

Note: from docs "The body or content of the POST must be the file itself in binary format."

Here is React component below

```jsx
import React, { Fragment, useState, useRef } from "react";
import { Col, Button, Media, Card, CardBody } from "reactstrap";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { attachMMS } from "../../../actions/index";
import cloudUpload from "../../../assets/img/icons/cloud-upload.svg";

const InsertMMS = ({
  showFileModal,
  setShowFileModal,
  showInsertMMSModal,
  setShowInsertMMSModal,
  uploadMMS,
  setUploadMMS,
}) => {
  const InputFile = useRef(null);
  const [userMMS, setUserMMS] = useState();
  const [highlighted, setHighlighted] = useState(false);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const attachMMSCreate = useSelector((state) => state.attachMMSCreate);

  const manualMMSUpload = (e) => {
    console.log("manualMMSUpload ran");
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.target.files[0].name) {
      console.log("file", e.target.files[0]);
      getBinary(e.target.files[0]);
      setUserMMS(e.target.files[0].name);
    }
  };

  const getBinary = (file) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    reader.onload = () => {
      setUploadMMS({ file: file, fileType: file.type });
    };
  };

  const handleInputChange = ({ value, name }) =>
    setUploadMMS({ ...uploadMMS, [name]: value });

  const onButtonClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    InputFile.current.click();
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Card>
        <CardBody className="fs--1 font-weight-normal p-4">
          <h4 className="mb-1 mt-3 text-center"></h4>
          <div>
            <input
              type="file"
              onChange={(e) => manualMMSUpload(e)}
              accept=".gif, .png, .jpeg"
              ref={InputFile}
              className="d-none"
            />
            <div
              className={`mb-2 p-3 border-dashed border-2x border-300 bg-light rounded-soft text-center cursor-pointer ${
                highlighted ? " border-800" : ""
              }`}
              onClick={(e) => onButtonClick(e)}
              onDragEnter={() => {
                setHighlighted(true);
              }}
              onDragLeave={() => {
                setHighlighted(false);
              }}
              onDragOver={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
              }}
              onDrop={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
              }}
            >
              <Fragment>
                <Media className=" fs-0 mx-auto d-inline-flex align-items-center">
                  <img src={cloudUpload} alt="" width={25} className="mr-2" />
                  <Media>
                    <p className="fs-0 mb-0 text-700">
                      {userMMS ? userMMS : "Upload your File"}
                    </p>
                  </Media>
                </Media>
                <p className="mb-0 w-75 mx-auto text-500">
                  Supports: .gif, .png, .jpeg{" "}
                </p>
              </Fragment>
            </div>
          </div>
          <p className="fs-0 text-center">multi-media message</p>
          <Col className="text-center">
            <Button
              disabled={!uploadMMS}
              color="primary"
              onClick={() => {
                return (
                  dispatch(attachMMS(uploadMMS)),
                  setShowInsertMMSModal(!showInsertMMSModal),
                  setShowFileModal(!showFileModal)
                );
              }}
              className="my-3 text-white"
            >
              {attachMMSCreate.loading ? "...processing" : "Attach MMS"}
            </Button>
          </Col>
        </CardBody>
      </Card>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default InsertMMS;
```

Here is the Action being called from React making the POST request to Node.js server

```js
export const attachMMS = (uploadMMS) => async (dispatch) => {
  console.log("body of attachMMS in actions", uploadMMS);
  try {
    dispatch({ type: ATTACH_MMS_CREATE_REQUEST });
    await axios({
      url: "http://localhost:5000/mms",
      method: "POST",
      data: uploadMMS.file,
      withCredentials: true,
    }).then((res) =>
      dispatch({ type: ATTACH_MMS_CREATE_SUCCESS, payload: res })
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    dispatch({
      type: ATTACH_MMS_CREATE_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.message && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

Here is the Node.js route being triggered

```js
module.exports = (router) => {
  router.route("/mms").post(twilCtrl.createMediaMMSResource);
};
```

Here is the Node.js function being called

```js
const createMediaMMSResource = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { subActServiceSid, subActAuthToken, convoServiceSid } = req.user;
    let mediaResource;

    await axios({
      url: `https://mcs.us1.twilio.com/v1/Services/${convoServiceSid}/Media`,
      method: "POST",
      data: req.body, // this needs to be the file itself in binary format
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "image/png",
      },
      auth: { username: subActServiceSid, password: subActAuthToken },
      withCredentials: true,
    }).then((res) => {
      console.log(
        "res from first post request to twilio with fileData",
        res.data
      );
      return (mediaResource = {
        mediaUrl: res.data.url,
        serviceSid: res.data.service_sid,
        mediaSid: res.data.sid,
      });
    });
    res.status(201).json(mediaResource);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

Here is the response I get from client....

Does anyone see the issue? I cant seem to understand how to send "Binary" data to node.js server.....

[image]

Comment: In JavaScript, binary data is typically represented using [typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays) (most commonly a [`Uint8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array), in which each array element is equal to a single byte).

Comment: i think you'll have to send the whole file as form-data and use multer middleware to extract the file from req body. And don't forget to send **content-type:multipart/form-data** when you send a POST request or whatever HTTP method you're using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to [send binary data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data#sending_binary_data) from the browser which you can handle in Express via the [`express.raw()`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.raw) middleware however
I would do the following instead...

1. [Upload the file to your Express service via `FormData`](https://github.com/axios/axios#files-posting). This is typically how browsers perform binary uploads and utilities like Axios make it even easier.

   ```js
   const manualMMSUpload = (e) => {
     if (e.target.files.length > 0) {
       const file = e.target.files[0];
       setUploadMMS({ file, fileType: file.type });
       setUserMMS(file.name);
     }
   };
   ```

   ```js
   // export const attachMMS = (uploadMMS) => async (dispatch) => {
   // ...

   // use axios.postForm()
   const res = await axios.postForm("http://localhost:5000/mms", {
     file: uploadMMS.file
   }, { withCredentials: true }); // do you actually need cookies?
   dispatch({type: ATTACH_MMS_CREATE_SUCCESS, payload: res})

   // ...
   ```

   FYI you do not need `withCredentials` unless you're relying on cookies.

   If you're on an older version of Axios without `postForm`, use the following

   ```js
   const data = new FormData();
   data.append("file", uploadMMS.file);
   const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/mms", data);
   ```
2. Handle the file upload in your Express service using the [Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) or [express-fileupload](https://github.com/richardgirges/express-fileupload) middleware.

   ```js
   const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
   router.route('/mms').post(fileUpload(), twilCtrl.createMediaMMSResource)
   ```
3. Pass the uploaded file buffer through to the upstream API.

   ```js
   const response = await axios.post(
     `https://mcs.us1.twilio.com/v1/Services/${convoServiceSid}/Media`,
     req.files.file.data, // here's the buffer
     {
       auth: { username: subActServiceSid, password: subActAuthToken },
       headers: {
         "content-type": req.files.file.mimetype,
       },
     }
   );
   ```

   This should upload the file data buffer as raw binary data.

Comment: Phil, Thanks so much. I was missing the middleware (multer or express-fileupload) I used express-fileupload. your solution works as long as you have axios version "0.27.0" or later. I have axios "0.21.0" on my machine. I will elaborate on your answer that worked for me. Thank you so much this should be part of twilio docs when sending MMS via conversations api. @philnash

Comment: @ErikaPeterson007 any reason you can't use latest Axios? I'll update my answer to show how to use earlier versions

Comment: its that axios.postForm, in my version I got axios.postForm is not a function. Just had to manually make formData in client and add "content-type: multipart/form-data" header when making axios post

Comment: @ErikaPeterson007 [You don't need to add content-type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68643919/283366). See my updated answer

Comment: your right, no need for content-type, I just needed to manually make the formData in client